# RecyclerView scrolls slowly with three elements and ImageViews in the items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, imageview

I'm trying to make a simple recycler view that currently only shows three card views, each with an image pushed to the left. Since there are only three items right now, all the card views are visible on the screen and there is nothing to scroll to. However, when I try to scroll, the semi-circular scroll glow indicator at the top or the bottom of the screen shows up and acts very laggy and jank. (This thing: [scroll-glow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4spe6.jpg))

I've found that if I comment out the line:

```
holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getDrawableId());
```

in `onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position)`, then the jank goes away, and the "scroll glow" indicator acts smooth and fluid.

`currentItem.getDrawableId()` just looks up the resource that's saved in a 2d array, like this:

```
private static int[][] resources = {{R.drawable.00, R.drawable.01}, {R.drawable.10, R.drawable.11}};
...
return resources[mX][mY];
```

I've also noticed that if I just replace `currentItem.getDrawableId()` with a hard coded `R.drawable.p00` then it also acts smooth. So, I think there's something weird with each item having a different resource...? Or maybe 2d array lookups are slow.....?

Lastly, I have the lines:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

and they don't seem to do anything for this scroll glow jank.

So, what could be causing this jank, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you check the images size , because of image size if larger in size its scroll slow.

Comment: Check your image resolution and size. For loading images use _Glide_ or _Picasso_

Comment: @Abhishekkumar So, my images are a little big, but wouldn't it be slow even if I manually insert a drawable resource?

Comment: @Piyush I'll look into Glide and Picasso, but it very much feels like overkill for such a simple problem. Why can't I just list my drawable IDs in an array and look them up, just like I'm doing?